# Multiway frequency function in Python?

Tags: python, function

This is my function:

```
def freq(*var):
    from functools import reduce
    from operator import getitem
    for c,i in enumerate(reversed(var)): 
        d={k:0 for k in set(i)} if c==0 else {k:d for k in set(i)}
    for row in zip(*var):
        *k,last_k=row
        reduce(getitem,k,d)[last_k]+=1

    return d
```

`var` argument would look like `(['a','b','b','c'],['one','two','two','two'])`

I am trying to return a nested dictionary that holds a frequency count. So result `d` should look like:

```
{'a':{'one':1, 'two':0}, 'b':{'one':0, 'two':2}, 'c':{'one':0, 'two':1}}
```

However my function returns, which is wrong:

```
{'a': {'one': 1, 'two': 3}, 'b': {'one': 1, 'two': 3}, 'c': {'one': 1, 'two': 3}}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Every dict at a given nesting level is the same dict here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all nested dicts in `d` dict is the same object. Use [dict.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.copy#dict.copy) method to fix problem, so changing line:

```
d={k:0 for k in set(i)} if c==0 else {k:d for k in set(i)}
```

to

```
d={k:0 for k in set(i)} if c==0 else {k:d.copy() for k in set(i)}
```

Would fix your problem. See more on [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types) and [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Good Luck!

Comment: @LMc does it answers your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You've somehow initialized **d**'s values to the same dictionary.  I can't fix this confidently, since I don't have Python3 installed here (blush).  However, I think the problem is that **k:d** value in the middle line: I think it plugs the identical default dictionary into each value.  Try creating a *new* empty dictionary for each pass through this iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the inner dict is referencing the same object and everything gets updated simultenously, as seen from the `enumerate` loop:

```
for c,i in enumerate(reversed(var)): 
     d={k:0 for k in set(i)} if c==0 else {k:d for k in set(i)}
#                                            ^
```

The inner dictionary `d` used in the second iteration of the loop is the same object. You can use `d.copy()` in place of `d` to create multiple copies for each key.

---

But why go through all the trouble of using `reduce` on `getitem`. That part of your code is quite hard to debug.

You can achieve the same thing by using a `Counter` object on your *zipped* items:

```
from collections import Counter

var = ['a','b','b','c'],['one','two','two','two']

c = Counter(zip(*var))
d = {k[0]: {j: v if j in k else 0 for j in set(var[1])} for k,v in c.items()}
print(d)
# {'b': {'two': 2, 'one': 0}, 'c': {'two': 1, 'one': 0}, 'a': {'two': 0, 'one': 1}}
```

Comment: `var` may have one or more elements. Here I used two, but it could have more or less.

Comment: The code can be extended by creating deeper nests in the dict comprehension. You can make this dynamic by refactoring it into a loop that takes cognizance to the number of elements in `var`